# dynamically retrieving images from server using in list view android

Tags: php, android, json

i am new at android have created database with different users with each one having image URL, now want to retrieve images URL from database of particular user and display in android list view.

public class SnapflowActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imagesList;
private static String url_all_images = "PHP FILE URL";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ALBUM_PICS = "album_pics";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// images JSONArray
JSONArray album_pics = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.snapflow);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    imagesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading images in Background Thread
    new LoadAllImages().execute();

    ListView lv = getListView();

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all Images by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SnapflowActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Images. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All images from url
     * */

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_images, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All images: ", json.toString());
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of images
                album_pics = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ALBUM_PICS);

                // looping through All images
                for (int i = 0; i < album_pics.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = album_pics.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    imagesList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no images found
                // Launchnew activity Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SnapflowActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all images
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SnapflowActivity.this, imagesList,
                        R.layout.list_image, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.id,
                                R.id.imageview1 });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Comment: if you dont show us your code we may not be able to help you.....show us your listview adapter and how you get data from database!

Comment: and do you get any errors in your logcat???

Comment: 404 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

Ok in order to do what you want i modified your class a bit and created some extra classes.

EDITED class:

```
public class SnapflowActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<ParseItem> imagesList;
private static String url_all_images = "PHP FILE URL";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ALBUM_PICS = "album_pics";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// images JSONArray
JSONArray album_pics = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.snapflow);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    imagesList = new ArrayList<ParseItem>();

    // Loading images in Background Thread
    new LoadAllImages().execute();

    ListView lv = getListView();

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all Images by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllImages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SnapflowActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Images. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All images from url
     * */

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_images, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All images: ", json.toString());
        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of images
                album_pics = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ALBUM_PICS);

                // looping through All images
                for (int i = 0; i < album_pics.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = album_pics.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    //I CREATED A CLASS ParseItem to CREATE THE LIST YOU WANT
                    imagesList.add(new ParseItem(id, name));
                }
            } else {
                // no images found
                // Launchnew activity Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SnapflowActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all images
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(SnapflowActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, imagesList);
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

The Custom Adapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseItem>{

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ParseItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItems holder;
        View rootView = null;
        ParseItem current = null;

        if(rootView == null){
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            rootView = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            current = getItem(position);

            holder = new ViewHolderItems();
            holder.id = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewForList);
            holder.name = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageForList);
            rootView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolderItems)rootView.getTag();
        }

        if(current != null){
            holder.id.setText(current.getId());
            Ion.with(holder.name).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).load(current.getName());
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    static class ViewHolderItems {
        TextView id;
        ImageView name;
    }

}
```

The ParseItem Class:

```
public class ParseItem {
    private String id, name;

    public ParseItem(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The list_item.xml layout for each listView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageForList" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewForList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in order to get the images with the easy way, compile the following dependency:

`compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'`

Hope it helps!!!!

Comment: where should i add above two class

Comment: can i know y Ion is used in MyCustomAdapter class